# How do you view cookies set via AJAX CORS requests in Chrome dev tools?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, cors

I'm seeing rather confusing behaviour in Chrome. Cookies that I set via a cross-origin AJAX request don't show up in the browser's dev tools inspector. I'm sure they're being set but there's no way of viewing them locally.

### I want to use Chrome devtools to view cookies that have been set by my API

My front end is a SPA and hosted on a different server to my (Rails) API. When testing locally, they're merely different ports: one is on `locahost:3000` and the other is on `localhost:4200`. So that I can use cookies with API requests, I've set my serverside CORS policy to allow for `withcredentials`. On the client, I have set my (Angular) cross-origin requests to have the header `withCredentials=true`.

### I've verified that the server is actually sending the cookie to the browser

When I make a request to the server, the server sets the cookie and I can see it in the response headers:

[image]

### ...but it doesn't shows up in Chrome devtools (or Safari)

[image]

### I know it's set successfully becuase it shows up in subsequent requests

I would have assumed that the cookie had simply failed to be set but when I inspect the next request to the API I can see the cookie both in the request payload in Chrome:

[image]

And it also shows up on the (Rails) server in the `request.cookies`

```
pry> request.cookies
=> {
 "my_cookie"=>"its value"}
```

#### Why can't I inspect this cookie in Chrome?

And is there a way to get around it - either in Chrome or in a different inspector? I just want a way to view and verify these cookies.

Comment: did you ever get to the bottom of this? I have a similar scenario and do not understand why they don't show up.

Comment: I can’t remember what I ended up concluding I’m afraid. I also can’t recall much of the tech. One thing I do recall is that I ended up abandoning the use of some level of encrypted / access prohibited cookie. I remember it being possible to set a cookie in a way that the JavaScript couldn’t access it and it only got sent to the server. However I gave up on that as I just couldn’t make it work. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! I too am still unsure!

Comment: I am facing a similar situation. Any idea on why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are set on the browser by the client application, from your screenshots, you are inspecting the server on port 4200 instead of your client application running on port 3000

Comment: It's a good thought and I considered the same but I don't think cookies are set specific to a port. Also I have tried going directly to the API at localhost:3000 to inspect them there and they *still* don't show up :/

Answer (score 0):

This should show up as a seperate "Cookies" tab when you inspect the XHR request. It's easy to miss because the tab only shows when withCredentials is set to true. [image: Screenshot of "Cookies" tab]